# difference between time columns with GMT plus information

Tags: postgresql, time

I have one time column as time data type -

```
2022-05-12 00:46:00.000 +0500
```

and the other as string -

```
May 11 2022, 07:14:10 PM
```

how do I get a new column with the difference between the two? How would I deal with the pesky +0500? never used this before.

Comment: A `time` data type does not contain a date. Do you mean `timestamp`?

Comment: yes sorry, it is timestamp